# How to prevent page from redirecting if false? (HTML/JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova, if-statement

Using - HTML, JavaScript, JQueryMobile, Phonegap. (One page architecture, all pages are on one html page)

I have an if/else statement for user login, so the if statement directs the user to `#page4` (if user/pass found in the database) which works perfectly fine, however I currently have a notification for the else statement but the issue is that after the notification it redirects the user back to the index page instead of remaining on the same page and allowing the user to try again.

What can I put in the else to prevent the page from redirecting off the current page, so that users can have another attempt at signing in?

**See below my current code**

```js
function loginUser()
{
  db = window.openDatabase("SoccerEarth", "2.0", "SoccerEarthDB", 2*1024*1024);
  db.transaction(loginDB, errorCB);
}

function loginDB(tx)
{
  var Username = document.getElementById("username").value;
  var Password = document.getElementById("password").value;
  tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM SoccerEarth WHERE UserName='" + Username + "' AND Password= '" + Password + "'", [], renderList);

}
function renderList(tx,results) {
  if (results.rows.length > 0) {
    navigator.notification.alert("Login Success!");
    window.location = "#page4";
  }
  else
  {
    navigator.notification.alert("Incorrect!");
    return false;
  }
}
```

Event -

```
  <div data-role="content">

    <form>
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <input type="text" id="username">
        <br>
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" >

        <input type="submit" value="Sign In" onclick="return loginUser()">

    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: you could redirect the user on the same page  like `window.location = "#loginPage";` ?

Comment: have you tried `ev.preventDefault()` ?

Comment: Please post the code that is calling `loginUser()`

Comment: (window.location = "#loginPage";) Just tried this and it did work, however after the alert "incorrect" appears, it takes the user very briefly to the index page but then quickly returns back to the login page. How can I prevent this occurring?

Comment: @toomanyredirects I have updated the code.

Comment: `return loginUser()` in your submit button will return the result from the `loginUser()` function, but that function does not return a result. It needs to return false/true.

Comment: @toomanyredirects So shall I change to the loginDB function?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `onclick` for button, use `<form onsubmit="return loginUser()">`

Answer (score 0):

Try setting action attribute to the form with #.

`<form action='#'>
     //your html code...
</form>`

Comment: @Mahdi- Did my answer helped you?

Comment: Not sure what you mean? Can you show me the example with my code

Comment: What is the # supposed to do? I have the form action already for return loginUser.

Comment: It will not allow the page to redirect I suppose.. you didn't mention the action attribute to the form in the question right?

Comment: I have updated the html part of my code, please see above and let me know how you think I should adjust the code. I've tried several things and it looks like window.location = "#loginPage"; is the only one that works, however even when the page redirects back to it's current page, it has a blink back to the index page or around 2 seconds before it returns.

Comment: did you edit the question? I didn't find any changes to the html code.